# Javascript for survey to pop up on Modal window instead of page load

Tags: javascript, survey, qualtrics, intercept

I am not sure if this problem is appropriate here, but I am building a survey in Qulatrics and
Right now, in Qualtrics we can trigger a survey that is linked to a specific page load. I want to trigger a survey using link calls with a modal within a single-page application (SPA), specifically when a confirmation pop-up appears.
Right now the pop-up window (modal) is on an already loaded page and not a separate page load itself which is usually where all the intercepts are triggered off. Which makes it hard to connect the intercept with this pop up as I am not aware of a way to trigger survey based on this pop-up window.
Does anyone know if I can integrate a functionality in the SPA using link calls (JavaScript events) to trigger the display of survey or intercept based on this popup modal instead of a page load.

This is what i tried so far.

1. identify modal window which is an event listener "confirmation-modal-shown"
   I need help with the javascript and placement part.

   javascript
   // Qualtrics API call to trigger a survey
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('customField', 'customValue'); // Set any custom data if needed
   });
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.displaySurveys();